# Unity - Avoid quad clipping or set rendering order

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 5 to develop a game. I'm still learning, so this may be a dumb question. I have read about Depth Buffer and Depth Texture, but I cannot seem to understand if that applies here or not.

My setting is simple: I create a grid using several quads (40x40) which I use to snap buildings. Those buildings also have a base, made with quads. Every time I put one one the map, the Quads overlap and they look like the picture.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the red quad is "merging" with the floor (white quads).

How can I make sure Unity renders the red one first, and the white ones are background? Of course, I can change the red quad Y position, but that seems like the wrong way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue, called [Z-Fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

Usually you can reduce it by reducing the range of “Clipping Planes” of the camera, but in your case the quads are at the same Y position, **so you can’t avoid it without changing the Y position**.

I don't know if it is an option for you, but if you use SpriteRenderer (Unity 2D) you don’t have that problem and you can just set “Sorting Layer” or “Order in Layer” if you want modify the rendering order.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how it is called. Bummer that there is not a more robust way of solving it. I guess I will have to disable the quads underneath too.